# ASP.NET Generic Runtime Error when opening a PDF in new tab - Stopped working

Tags: vb.net, pdf, runtime-error, iis-8

I am hosting my site with Windows Server 2012 running IIS8.  The code is written in VB.NET.

Up until yesterday, my pages would open PDF's in a new tab for viewing (not download) after a link button is clicked.  The link button would work only if the associated file exists in the database.

```
        If (myreader(49) = "" And myreader(52).ToString() = "0") Then
            lnkAttachment.Text = "N/A"
            lnkAttachment.Enabled = False
        Else
            lnkAttachment.Text = "Click Here"
            lnkAttachment.Enabled = True
```

Once the button is clicked it would open the PDF in a new tab.  It stopped working and now shows a generic Runtime Error.

[image: Runtime Error shown]

The code that generates the link to this page is:

```
Protected Sub lnkAttachment_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkAttachment.Click
    Dim wdwOpen As String = "window.open('" & "../Attachment/" & Session("ID") & ".pdf" & "','_blank');"
    Response.Write("<script>")
    Response.Write(wdwOpen)
    Response.Write("</script>")
End Sub
```

I have the web.config file and IIS Error Page Settings supposed to be showing detailed error information:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

[image: IIS Setting]

I have multiple applications setup under this IIS site.  The one with the problem (WO) is the only one I cannot open PDF's in.  I have another application under this site that has no issues displaying the PDF file.  I want to say this is an IIS issue but I cannot pinpoint what the error is.

I have gone into the C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 file and found this line:

```
2016-07-20 13:29:22 (server ip address) GET /WO/Attachment/40147.pdf - 443 - 192.168.0.2 Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+CPU+iPhone+OS+9_3_2+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/601.1.46+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/9.0+Mobile/13F69+Safari/601.1 - 500 0 0 31
```

It shows a 500 error but for the life of me I cannot solve this problem.  I have found a plethora of information through web searches, but I cannot find one to the specific problem.  How does the code work one day and then stop the next, and only for one application under a site in IIS.

Any ideas as to what can be the problem?

EDIT:
Excerpt from Event Viewer per illinoistim Comment:

```
Event code: 3008 
Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
Event time: 7/21/2016 6:55:26 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/21/2016 11:55:26 AM 
Event ID: 949451611c784e7695ead3f75ea8d6b5 
Event sequence: 125 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
  Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/WO-15-131135755702094878 
  Trust level: Full 
  Application Virtual Path: /WO 
  Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OHAS\WODB\ 
  Machine name: (Machine Name) 

Process information: 
  Process ID: 22580 
  Process name: w3wp.exe 
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
  Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
  Exception message: It is an error to use a section registered as    allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OHAS\WODB\attachment\web.config line 86)
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Identity()
  at System.Web.HttpContext.SetImpersonationEnabled()
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)



Request information: 
  Request URL: (site URL)
  Request path: /WO/attachment/40147.pdf 
  User host address: 192.168.20.1 
  User:  
  Is authenticated: False 
  Authentication Type:  
  Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
  Thread ID: 57 
  Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
  Is impersonating: False 
  Stack trace:    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
  at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_Identity()
  at System.Web.HttpContext.SetImpersonationEnabled()
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)


Custom event details:
```

Comment: Have you checked your event viewer?  It should give you some more details.

Comment: I have not.  Where in the event viewer should I be looking?

Comment: Under custom views, select Administrative Events. Try to duplicate the error and hit the refresh icon on the right side.  The recent error should display with an explanation.

Comment: @illinoistim, I placed the results in the Question Block

Comment: @illinoistim, I figured it out.  Answer below.  Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here was the deal.  Thanks to illinoistim's comments about going to the event viewer, I was able to use the content to search around.

Apparently I had inadvertently copied the web.config file from the root folder into the attachment sub folder.  I was going to make changes to my web.config file so I copied it to a temp folder on my desktop in case things went sideways.  I suspect that since I have a programmable mouse, and the file was still stored in the clipboard, I must have had the attachment folder selected and hit my "paste" button on the mouse.  Both .config files have the tag .  This tag is only allowed at the application level.

Comment: Glad to help.  The event viewer helps a lot, especially in a production environment where you can't turn off the custom errors.  Make sure you do have custom errors on when making your site live.